# Text on top of a hotspot prevents hotspot responding

Tags: html, css

I'm building a web page that has a background image. On top of this I have a semi-transparent image of a CD (opacity 0.2) and created a hotspot around the CD image using Dreamweaver, I then added a link and it all works fine. Next I added text in the center of the CD image and now the hotspot doesn't respond when I mouseover the text at the center of the image. I'm working on the CD image at the bottom left of the page which can be seen here http://lawenforcementspanish.com/chris/index3.php .

Thanks for any direction you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="homePageCd fltlft">
  <div class="text_over_image">Hear my<br>music</div>
<img src="images/CDimage.png" usemap="#Map" style="opacity:0.2" border="0">
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="circle" coords="129,129,124" href="discography.php">
</map>

</div>
```

Your div which contains text overlaps the image and the anchor.

put   `<div class="text_over_image">Hear my<br>music</div>` before the `img`

Comment: @TonyBabb you can vote the answer up if the answer helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `text_over_image` behind the image by placing it before the `img` in your html markup. However, if you wish to keep the text actually on top you can use `pointer-event:none` to make the element hidden to hover and click events.

Simply add it to your CSS:

```
.text_over_image {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

However, it is worth noting that [CSS Pointer Events isn't well supported in old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

Comment: Thank you for an elegant solution and the link to browser compatibility, that was most helpful.